# Adding to array, then loop through and SUM contents

Tags: jquery, arrays, sum, listitem

There are already a few other posts on SO for this topic, like: [Loop through array and return sum of all values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328000/loop-through-array-and-return-sum-of-all-values). I have used the techniques from there and am still not getting the right result.

I have a UL with Several LI's in it. Each of those LI's has text in them which I need adding to an array, once they have all been added I need to add them up.

**JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/4Be6N/**

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var arrTotals = [];
var totalAmount = 0;

$( ".cartprice" ).each(function( index ) {

    arrTotals.push = $(this).text(); 
    console.log(arrTotals);
});

for (var i = 0; i < arrTotals.length; i++) {
    totalAmount += arrTotals[i] << 0;
}

console.log('Total Amount: ' + totalAmount)   

});
```

However, the console is displaying:

**Total Amount: 0**

Can anyone see why?

Comment: arrTotals.push($(this).text()); works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var arrTotals = [];
    var totalAmount = 0;

    $( ".cartprice" ).each(function( index ) {

        arrTotals[index] = $(this).text(); 
        console.log(arrTotals[index]);
        totalAmount+=parseFloat($(this).text());
   });

    console.log('Total Amount: ' + totalAmount)   

});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Be6N/4/)

Comment: Can you help me with something else. When I add $('#thetotal').text(newTotalAmount); the result is NaN ?

Comment: Yes why not, but you have variable totalAmount and where is newTotalAmount?

Comment: please share your code on jsfiddle so that i can help you better.

Comment: When I add it in JSFiddle it works: http://jsfiddle.net/4Be6N/9/ but not on the website :/

Comment: check for console error. for more information http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Answer (score 0):

I think shortest way possible something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var totalAmount = 0;
    $(".cartprice").each(function (index) {
        totalAmount += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });
    console.log('Total Amount: ' + totalAmount);
});
```